# usar PHP, Mysql y Javascritp para calcular precio de venta de producto

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

En un formulario tengo un select que muestra los articulos de la tabla "producto":

```
           <select name="producto" id="producto" class="form-control">
                <?php
                    require_once("config/config.php");
                    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost',  DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
                        $result = $conexion->query(" SELECT id_producto, nombre_producto
                        from producto   ORDER BY id_producto ASC" );
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                                echo '<option value="'.$row['id_producto'].'">'.$row['nombre_producto'].'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                ?>
            </select>
```

luego tengo un select que me muestra el precio de venta del articulo seleccionado, a traves de una funcion javascript:

```
                   <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                        <label for="precio">Precio de Venta</label>
                        <select name="precio" id="precio" class="form-control" readonly=""></select>
                    </div>
```

aqui la funcion:

```
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#producto").on('change', function () {
                $("#producto option:selected").each(function () {
                    var id_producto = $(this).val();
                    $.post("subcategories.php", { id_producto: id_producto }, function(data) {
                        $("#precio").html(data);
                    });         
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

luego, tengo un input cantidad:

```
           <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="number" name = "cantidad" class="form-control input-sm" id="cantidad">
            </div>
```

y finalmente, tengo un input numerico donde pretendo mostrar el calculo: Total = precio * cantidad

```
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="subtotal">SubTotal</label>
        <input type="number" name = "subtotal"class="form-control input-sm" id="subtotal" readonly="">
    </div>
```

El archivo "subcategories.php", retorna el id y precio del producto seleccionado:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $html = '';
 require_once("config/config.php");
 $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

 $id_producto = $_POST['id_producto'];

 $result = $conexion->query("SELECT id_producto, precio_venta 
FROM producto WHERE id_producto = ".$id_producto." ");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $html .= '<option    
      value="'.$row['id_producto'].'">'.$row['precio_venta'].'  </option>';
 }
}
echo $html;
?>
```

La pregunta viene dada por la circunstancia que, al momento de hacer el calculo:

```
$('#cantidad').on('change', function(){
                //Obtenemos el precio de venta
                let precio = $('#precio').val();
                //Obtenemos la cantidad
                let cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
                //Multiplicamos ambos valores
                let subtotal = precio * cantidad;
                //Asignamos el resultado al value de subtotal
                $('#subtotal').val(subtotal);
                });
```

el valor que me retorna la variable "precio" es el id del producto.
alguna idea de como hacer para traer exactamente el valor "precio"?
Gracias.

Comment: Haz un console log de las variables para saber qué se está pasando mal

Comment: hola @PadronRocha, como lo comenté en la pregunta, el valor de la variable "precio", (que viene dado por el select ubicado en el archivo "subcategories.php"), es la que está causando problemas ya que retorna es el "id" del producto y no su precio.